# SensorExtension Raw HRM data to BPM

Tags: java, android

I've been looking to build a very simple heart rate monitor as a project to experiment with the sensors on the Samsung Note 4, in particular the heart rate sensor under the camera. I've been granted the SensorExtension sdk by Samsung and have run their sample activity that will display the raw data of the sensor.

I was wondering if someone can give me a nudge in the right direction as to how to convert the raw data into meaningful beats per minute data. I know it involves a lot of signal processing but any help would be appreciated as i'd rather not rely on Samsung Digital Health sdk.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am working on the same project.  I just ran the sample app.  After looking at the data in a graph it appears we are going to have to collect a sample of data and then look for the rate of change.  I think this will become much clearer if you grab a sample of the data and graph it. If I find out more I'll let you know.

Answer (score 1):

If you add a time stamp to the data you can count the peaks and troughs per second. I show this using an excel spreadsheet below.  The same method could be easily translated to your Android code.

[image: Time stamped Data]

I also found this information on whats hidden within that Data:
[PPG Signal](http://www.valencell.com/blog/2015/10/optical-heart-rate-monitoring-what-you-need-know)
In the mentioned link they describe exactly what is hidden within the data  shown in this image

[image: PPG Signal]

I hope this helps.